# Question disappeared?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, auto-delete

I asked a question like a year ago. It was pretty detailed. Recently I realized I lost my notes on this so I thought I could just go and look the question. The problem is that I cannot find it.

Is there a mechanism that deletes inactive questions? Or am I going crazy here?

It didn't have any answers, comments or votes whatsoever. Does this matter?

EDIT: Apparently it was deleted due to inactivity.

So could a moderator search for a complex analysis question with "Hadamard product" in it's title (or in the text) please?

Comment: Yes, it matters. Questions which receive no input get deleted after some time. Do you have a link?

Comment: Oh, no. I am not even sure about the title. I don't. Is there any way to retrieve it?

Comment: Was it http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1389942/picards-theorem-analogue-for-difference-equations ?

Comment: Ah, no. I can still see that. It even was upvoted once.

Comment: It was about complex analysis. I am trying to extend analytically a horrible triple sum. I used Hadamard product to get an integral. So it is a decent guess that "Hadamard product" appears in the title.

Comment: Essentially all deletions on the site are soft-deletions only. Nothing is really gone. It can just be difficult to track down deleted content. (You could see it if it's your own; with 10k  you can see all deleted posts.) If it is really important,  ask a moderator, they should be able to find it relatively easily, just like if it was not deleted. But try to be specific. Likely a mod will see this here soon. In general you could ask in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office

Comment: I have added ([meta-tag:specific-question]) tag, since you seem to be interested about the particular question you mentioned in your post. If the tag is not suitable (see [the tag-info](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info) for the usage guidance), feel free to remove it.

Comment: Your only deleted question that you haven't deleted yourself is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999733/convolution-and-singularities). That doesn't really match your description, though. Nor do your self-deleted questions. Have you maybe used another account at some time?

Comment: Oh, I see. I just realized that it could be on mathoverflow that I posted it. Are the moderators of the two sites different? Should I make a new post there? Sorry for all this.

Comment: By the way, it is very ironic that the question was deleted automatically and it has a comment that explains why it was deleted but I could not see it anyway. I don't see the point of that.

Comment: Yes, the moderators are different (but with nonempty intersection). You could make a post on their meta, or cast a custom flag on one of your posts, if you can explain it within the flag text limit (I don't remember whether that's 400 or 600 characters).

Comment: The issue was resolved. My question was undeleted. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Once my question disappeared as well... to this day, I do not know why, but I have my notes from it anyway because I wrote down the answer on paper and stuck it up on my door :)

Answer (score 4):

The general criterion for [automatic question deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) can be found on capital-M Meta.

In particular, if a question is more than one year old, has fewer than about 500 views, and has no answers, comments, or upvotes, then it will be deleted.

You can find more information about post deletion at [the Meta FAQ thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

Comment: Yes, I understand that now. But is it gone for ever? Can the text be found somehow?

Comment: It would be visible to you and to 10k+ users, but only if they could find it in the first place. This is [likely difficult](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19689/how-to-find-old-deleted-posts-of-my-own).

Comment: How do they appear for 10k users? I mean is there a specific category? Can they search for key words?

Comment: No, it's not searchable except for moderators. One of the privileges gained at 10k reputation is the ability to see all deleted posts; in practice, this is only possible if there is a link to it somewhere. An isolated year-old question that wasn't linked anywhere is extremely difficult to find. Sometimes you can find things in various caches, such as the [internet archive](https://archive.org/).

Comment: Strictly speaking, 10k+ users can also search for deleted posts, but only among their own posts. See, for example, [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13948/is-there-any-way-to-see-my-deleted-questions-or-answers/13949#13949).

Comment: A possible clue to automatically deleted questions is the granting of a Tumbleweed badge.  This ordinarily will occur long before the actual deletion, but the details visible to you would identify which Question occasioned the badge.  Unfortunately you will only earn the Tumbleweed badge once, so it is of no help if the Tumbleweed badge had been earned previously (as seems to be the case for this user).