# Where did my question go?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I asked a question previously on Math.SE.  Halfway through the question, I realized that I might have found a solution.  So I deleted the question, tried the solution; it didn't work.  Now I wish to restore the question so others can try answering it -- but, it's gone.  It's not even in my record of Posts.  How can I restore it?

[Similar post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24816/question-disappeared)

Comment: Obviously the following suggestion I have to offer will not help you *with this particular post*.  But it is better not to delete a question, before checking out your solution.  E.g., you could have posted, within your question, your solution attempt.  Users here are very good at finding errors, and posting an attempted solution helps them know what you know, and what you might not fully understand.

Comment: [This one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3940410/factoring-an-integral)

Comment: @amWhy My habit is to, not waste people's time if I can find a solution myself.  Because as a rule of thumb, if I post, people look at it, and then my solution does not work -- they will not look at it a second time.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, thank you.  I will go ahead and edit and un-delete it now.  Is there a reason it doesn't show up in my history of posts?  Maybe I'm not looking in the right place?

Comment: I think you could have found it via the [deleted recent questions link](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/48061) at the bottom of the "Questions" tab of your profile (visible only to the profile owner and moderators).

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah, OK; didn't look there.  Will look there if this happens again.  You should probably post this as an answer, in case others have a similar issue in the future.

Comment: See also: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948)

Answer (score 6):

One can find one's own recently (last $60$ days) deleted posts via a link

> [recently deleted questions/answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/-1)

at the bottom of the "Questions" or "Answers" tab of one's profile. (This link is only visible to the profile owner and moderators, it's nobody else's business. The link above uses the Id of the [Community ♦ bot](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), it won't work. Replace the "-1" with your own user number – or go via your profile.)

If the post has been deleted for longer, and your reputation is below $10$k<sup>(1)</sup>, you cannot locate it yourself (unless you find a link e.g. in your browser history). But if you ask nicely and provide enough details to make the search not too difficult, you may convince a moderator to locate it and provide you with a link to the post.

<sup>(1)</sup> Users with $\geqslant 10$k reputation can search for their own deleted posts with the search parameter "deleted:1" (or "deleted:all" to find the posts matching the other search parameters whether deleted or not).

Comment: The link you posted is broken...

Comment: I used the user-Id of the Community bot. Replace the "-1" with your user-Id.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Good point, thanks.